# How to subscribe to epic's output stream of actions in a component

Tags: redux, redux-observable

I'm refactoring `loadInstruments` thunk into redux-observable epic as it was doing more and more async stuff plus I needed cancellaction etc (typical wiki search scenario from tutorials).

This is how my component used this thunk (it was made available via `mapDispatchToProps`)

```
this.props.loadInstruments(queryParams).then(...)
```

Thunk was doing a bunch of things and one of them was AJAX call. It returned a  promise that I could wait for and then see the result of AJAX call (this result was also put into redux store).

However after refactoring to `redux-observable` and epic, I have no means to return a value from epic as my `loadInstruments` looks like this (it simply dispatches and action and epic's `ofType` is filtering):

```
const loadInstruments = ({ type: 'LAUNCH_LOAD_INSTRUMENTS_EPIC' })
```

When `LAUNCH_LOAD_INSTRUMENTS_EPIC` is caught by `ofType`, it is running with rxjs magic and once instruments (AJAX call) are loaded then they end up in store (by using `switchMap` and dispatching new action that updates the store).

But my component was using `loadInstruments` returned Promise settled value to quickly get what was fetched / put into the store. After refactoring to epic, I don't know how to get / return a value from `loadInstument`.

Is there a way to achieve something similar with `redux-observable` or I need to refactor my component? E.g.

```
loadInstruments(queryParams).subscribe(x => ...)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying there is a performance diff between the previous thunk magic and the new epic magic providing data to the component, or are you saying that what was previously occurring is no longer?

Comment: No performance diff. I'm refactoring because the process of loading instruments (AJAX request) became complicated: caching + debouncing + only if query params changed + cancelling previous if next search happens. Typical reactive scenario. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with redux-thunk anymore but if I understand correctly, previously the thunk was updating either component state or app (redux) state. When you refactored to use redux-observable you are no longer getting the updated value to the component.

That sounds like you just need to subscribe to state changes inside your component using redux `connect(mapState, mapDispatch)`
In this scenario, `mapDispatch` will wrap `loadInstruments` which I believe you already have working, and `mapState` will subscribe to the piece of state you update after dispatching an action from the epic.
You just need to make sure you epics "out" action includes the data to update the redux state with and that you are also subscribed to state changes in your component. eg

```
const myEpic = (action$) => 
action$.pipe(
  ofType(LAUNCH_LOAD_INSTRUMENTS_EPIC),
  /* ajax operators and whatever else*/
  mapTo({ type: OUT_ACTION_WITH_NEW_STATE instruments: {/*new state*/} })
)

/*reducer land...*/
if (action.type === OUT_ACTION_WITH_NEW_STATE) {
  return {...prevState, instruments: action.instruments}
}

/*component land*/
connect((state) => {instruments: state.instruments}, {loadInstruments})(myComponent)
```

To reference the title of your question, "subscribe to epic's output stream of actions in a component", you don't. Subscription happens in the redux-observable middleware. Therefore you never need to manually add the `subscribe()` call to the end of your stream. With redux-observable, the action flow is:

dispatch an action -> reducer -> epic -> action -> reducer -> epic -> action...(repeated)
If any components are subscribed to the redux store with `connect`, then when the store is updated, that component will receive the updated state as a `prop`.